# "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a" coming from jquery, only in firefox

Tags: jquery, compatibility, typeerror

This is sort of strange... I am getting a "TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a" error, but only when I use firefox (page works fine in chrome, but doesn't even load in firefox). Not only that, the source of the TypeError comes from http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/jquery@2.1,bootstrap@3.2 so it's not even part of my code.

If anyone knows anything about this please help.

Thanks.

Comment: This could be caused many things including compatibility issues, library issues, browser specific code in your application, etc.; thus, it may be challenging to answer this without knowing what your code looks like. Is this error just now happening? Please post a snippet of what you did last that you remember before the error started appearing and please describe what you have done to try to fix it. This is the best way to get great answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: well, the website is staged on a public address, and works fine in firefox. if i use the same file but local on firefox, it doesn't load. so i assume this has something to do with staging and CORS